# Tokenize JSON data using nltk

Tags: json, python-3.x, nltk

I am new to the field of NLP and trying to tokenize the word from text and JSON data. I could do it successfully for text data but unable to do it on JSON

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import json

with open('Data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

tokenized_text_json = word_tokenize(data)
```

It throws error that expected string or bytes-like object. But I know here 'data' is dictionary. Is there any method or library to store them as string?

I tried below code but it didn't work

`data = nltk.data.load("Data.json", "json")`

I would like to load the data in a format which can be used to tokenize. Thanks!

Comment: what does your json data look like? Can you share sample of the json content?

Comment: I am just trying on some sample JSON data
    {
    "nm": "Edmund lronside",
    "cty": "United Kingdom",
    "hse": "House of Wessex",
    "yrs": "1016"
  },
  {
    "nm": "Cnut",
    "cty": "United Kingdom",
    "hse": "House of Denmark",
    "yrs": "1016-1035"
  },
  {
    "nm": "Harold I Harefoot",
    "cty": "United Kingdom",
    "hse": "House of Denmark",
    "yrs": "1035-1040"
  }

Comment: I am puzzled about your requirement. You want to tokenize a JSON object? to what?

Comment: I need to perform entity extraction on JSON data; so I want tokenize the data first;I am first trying it on sample JSON data